# What does a star next to a song in the Music app in iOS indicate?

Tags: ios, music, apple-music, music.app

What does the star next to track #2 and #3 indicate in this screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like it indicates a song's popularity.

> @rjonesy It's an indication of the song's popularity in the iTunes
>   Store.

https://twitter.com/AppleSupport/status/720277245865107457

Answer (score 1):

It means that either Apple has used this song, or, it means it is a popular track.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. A single sentence is rarely (if ever) acceptable as an answer. Can you expand on this to back up your answer? For example, is there a source you can link to and summarise in your answer (in case the link breaks)?

Answer (score -1):

It's also the star rating that you've given a song/disc.  While listening to a song, tap the artwork.  From there you can give it 0-5 stars.  The stars will show-up next to the song, like in your image.

Comment: I just tried this out and it doesn't seem to correlate. Maybe you can show a screenshot with more than one star next to a song in the album list view?

Comment: It won't show more than 1 star next to it.  Every song/album I've "star'd" has the star next to it.  Maybe I just star popular songs?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could make a short video of rating a song on your device and a star appearing. But I understand if you can't.

Comment: My free Apple Music subscription expired so I can't access it anymore, sorry.

Comment: i can confirm that this is not what the star means.

Comment: @vas feel free to update the answer or add a new answer if your info is more accurate.

Comment: why? the accepted answer is spot on. seems like you don't want to accept that?

Comment: yes. and your answer is wrong. the accepted answer is right. if you don't get that, there's nothing more i can say.

Comment: No, if there already is a correct answer, why would you edit the others? That makes no sense. You downvote the wrong ones. And you're the one who made this extensive. I just pointed out that it was wrong, and you couldn't be rational about it, and made suggestions that made ZERO sense given that there is a correct answer already. Later!